# CSS url image not visible Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, html, css, pythonanywhere

I created a header where the text changes according to an output in the backend. However, the image that constitutes this header is not visible.

I put the image in the static file that constitutes my app and added the path to the image in the CSS code as well as in the static files section of the Web tab as follows :

*CSS code :*

```
.hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(47, 50, 51), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("/images/Ax8yBTP.jpg");
    height: 25%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

*Static files : /home/jejrhom1/mysite/static/images*

Would you know where the error comes from?

Thank you!

Comment: Do your CSS in a separate file? What is the path to this file?

Comment: Hello! Yes, the path is: /home/jejrhom1/mysite/static/content/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: This code `.hero-image` you wrote in bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I wrote an answer. Try the path prom there

Comment: There are a number of ways that static file serving can be misconfigured. PythonAnywhere has a help page [here](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/) that works through how you can debug your static files config.

Answer (score 0):

According to your path the correct is `url("/static/images/Ax8yBTP.jpg")`

Try to use relative path based on your css file location.
If you css path is like */home/jejrhom1/mysite/static/css/style.css* - so the correct path to the image will be

```
url("../images/Ax8yBTP.jpg");
```

`../` this part means we go one level back, to the folder `static`, where we see both `css` and `images`.

Comment: I have just tried this path and it is unfortunately not working...

Comment: And your image is  /home/jejrhom1/mysite/static/images/Ax8yBTP.jpg ?

Comment: Any live demo? Try for test to stet only `background-image: url("../images/Ax8yBTP.jpg");` without gradient and else, to see.

Comment: Actually, it works when I use the app locally but not in pythonanywhere. I deleted gradient and else, still not working. I will do more research and share the solution if there is any haha.